# Postgresql 10 - How to re-sequence a primary key column in a table which depends on other tables

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-18.04

I have a table called client which depends on input from other tables. with the following specs:

```
crewdb=#\d+ client;
                                                    Table "public.client"
       Column        |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |           Default            | Storage  | Stats target | Description
---------------------+---------+-----------+----------+------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 clientid            | integer |           | not null | generated always as identity | plain    |              |
 account_name        | text    |           | not null |                              | extended |              |
 last_name           | text    |           |          |                              | extended |              |
 first_name          | text    |           |          |                              | extended |              |
 address             | text    |           | not null |                              | extended |              |
 suburbid            | integer |           |          |                              | plain    |              |
 cityid              | integer |           |          |                              | plain    |              |
 post_code           | integer |           | not null |                              | plain    |              |
 business_phone      | text    |           |          |                              | extended |              |
 home_phone          | text    |           |          |                              | extended |              |
 mobile_phone        | text    |           |          |                              | extended |              |
 alternative_phone   | text    |           |          |                              | extended |              |
 email               | text    |           |          |                              | extended |              |
 quote_detailsid     | integer |           |          |                              | plain    |              |
 invoice_typeid      | integer |           |          |                              | plain    |              |
 payment_typeid      | integer |           |          |                              | plain    |              |
 job_typeid          | integer |           |          |                              | plain    |              |
 communicationid     | integer |           |          |                              | plain    |              |
 accessid            | integer |           |          |                              | plain    |              |
 difficulty_levelid  | integer |           |          |                              | plain    |              |
 current_lawn_price  | numeric |           |          |                              | main     |              |
 square_meters       | numeric |           |          |                              | main     |              |
 note                | text    |           |          |                              | extended |              |
 client_statusid     | integer |           |          |                              | plain    |              |
 reason_for_statusid | integer |           |          |                              | plain    |              |
Indexes:
    "client_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (clientid)
    "account_name_check" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (account_name)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "client_accessid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (accessid) REFERENCES access(accessid)
    "client_cityid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (cityid) REFERENCES city(cityid)
    "client_client_statusid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (client_statusid) REFERENCES client_status(client_statusid)
    "client_communicationid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (communicationid) REFERENCES communication(communicationid)
    "client_difficulty_levelid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (difficulty_levelid) REFERENCES difficulty_level(difficulty_levelid)
    "client_invoice_typeid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (invoice_typeid) REFERENCES invoice_type(invoice_typeid)
    "client_job_typeid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (job_typeid) REFERENCES job_type(job_typeid)
    "client_payment_typeid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (payment_typeid) REFERENCES payment_type(payment_typeid)
    "client_quote_detailsid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (quote_detailsid) REFERENCES quote_details(quote_detailsid)
    "client_reason_for_statusid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (reason_for_statusid) REFERENCES reason_for_status(reason_for_statusid)
    "client_suburbid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (suburbid) REFERENCES suburb(suburbid)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "work" CONSTRAINT "work_clientid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (clientid) REFERENCES client(clientid)
```

The column clientid (primary key) is out of order as client records where deleted as follows:

```
crewdb=# select clientid from client order by clientid asc limit 22;
 clientid
----------
        2
        3
        4
        5
        6
        7
        8
        9
       10
       11
       12
       13
       14
       15
       17
       19
       21
       22
       23
       24
       26
       30
(22 rows)
```

e.g. row 1 and 25 were deleted. Is there a way to restart the index from 1 increment by 1 taking the relationships to other tables into account and doing all that in a safe manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: In principle I like the idea of having ids nice and clean. However renumbering them offers no advantage if it succeeds, while will break the database if it fails.

First it is better to ensure yourself, that you are the [only user connected to the database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3185413/11748454). We will use transactions anyway, but that will help the database do its work faster.

Before you renumber the `client` table, you need to change the `FOREIGN KEY` constraints that reference the table:

> `Referenced by:
>       TABLE "work" CONSTRAINT "work_clientid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (clientid) REFERENCES client(clientid)`

and add the `CASCADE` action to `ON UPDATE` (cf. [CREATE TABLE reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE)):

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE work DROP CONSTRAINT work_clientid_fkey;
ALTER TABLE work ADD CONSTRAINT work_clientid_fkey
    FOREIGN KEY (clientid) REFERENCES client ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;
```

This will automatically update the `work.clientid` column, when the `client.clientid` column changes. When this is done we can use a `SELECT` statement to generate the new ids and use the result to issue an `UPDATE` statement, as [explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6258586/11748454). You can do it with:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE SEQUENCE temp_client_id;
-- The real work begins
UPDATE client
SET clientid = ids.new_id
FROM (SELECT clientid AS old_id, nextval('temp_client_id') AS new_id
      FROM client ORDER BY clientid) AS ids
WHERE clientid = ids.old_id;
-- Clean up
DROP SEQUENCE temp_client_id;
COMMIT;
```

After all this is done you might want to update the value of the sequence you are using to generate ids for the `client` table (let's call it `client_id_seq`):

```
SELECT setval('client_id_seq', MAX(clientid)) FROM client;
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed esplaination.